# Is Acer BlueLightShield (non Pro version) merely an application?

Tags: display, eye-strain, acer

I was looking at two entry level 75 Hz monitors from LG and Acer. Both have same basic functions.

The main difference I could see is LG (and other brands too) don't have anything specific like the Acer monitor - which says "Acer **BlueLightShield**" for eyes protection. LG and other brands also mention "eye care features" but nothing specific like Shield/Filter.

I read from official Acer website about [this technology](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/AU/content/acer-visioncare) and I found this table:

[image]

So as you can see, *BlueLightShield* has only *Acer VisionCare* and *BlueLightShield Pro* have *Acer VisionCare 2.0* onwards.

The same website page also mentions this about the *Pro* version:

> BlueLightShield Pro Eyesafe® Certified Displays emit at least 30% less
> high-energy blue light compared to the industry-standard LCDs -
> selectively reducing harmful blue light in the 415-455 nm wavelength
> range, while still maintaining a high degree of color accuracy.

So, I concluded that *BlueLightShield* doesn't have anything specific mentioned like they have mentioned about Pro version (30% less blue light).

And another thing I'm sure about is that the *BlueLightShield* (non Pro) doesn't have Eyesafe® certification.

---

I contacted Acer customer care they said they don't have this information on products page so they can't give information regarding this.

Now, **I want to understand if this *BlueLightShield* (non Pro version) is merely an application like Windows inbuilt Nightlight and other such free applications?**

OR does Acer actually have some hardware/physical component included in the monitor screen which is called as *Shield*?

PS: Personally, I feel it might not be a physical thing/part/hardware. Otherwise it would increase the monitor cost. The cost of many other brands' monitors is more or less same as this Acer monitor I was considering. So I feel it might be just an application.

Comment: It's all just marketing tosh for people who have read blue light is bad for you, without understanding that it isn't at such low levels as from a computer display. They also confuse 'harmful' with the fact that blue light tends to keep you awake at night - which is the *actual* purpose of various 'night' modes in displays. End result - the more you can claim your product is "Blue Light Certified™" the more people will believe the hype & buy it. https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/will-blue-light-from-electronic-devices-increase-my-risk-of-macular-degeneration-and-blindness-2019040816365)

Comment: I suspect these are hardware/firmware features, btw. Investing a bit of time into adding more 'marketing' features works, if they can sell 1% more product because people think it's "healthy" then it's worth their investment. If they don't do it & others do, they lose market share.

Comment: @Tetsujin also, I feel, if it were really very effective and really helps, it should have been a mandatory standard irrespective of what budget monitor you buy.

Comment: Vikas - yeah… if it was actually a 'danger to health' I'm sure it would be ;))